# printing a red triangle in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I have the following code and am trying to print a red triangle using opengl glew ect. The program builds and shows a triangle, however it only shows a triangle when I drag the window, and the triangle shows up white not red. Not sure how to fix this issue. Below is a copy of my code (I am running in xcode).

```
#include <iostream>

// GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

// GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>


static unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const std::string& source)
{
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (result != GL_FALSE)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char*  message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, message);
        std::cout << "Failed to compile " << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment") << "shader" << std::endl;
        std::cout << message << std::endl;

        glDeleteShader(id);
        return 0;
    }

    return id;
}

static unsigned int CreateShader(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader)
{
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return program;
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;

    float positions[6] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
         0.0f,  0.5f,
         0.5f, -0.5f
    };

    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), 0);

    std::string vertexShader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
        "\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "   gl_Position = position;\n"
        "}\n";

    std::string fragmentShader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "\n"
        "layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;\n"
        "\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "   color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n";

    unsigned int shader = CreateShader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    glUseProgram(shader);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteProgram(shader);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I am using xCode and am having 2 issues: 
1. the triangle is printing out white
2. the triangle only shows up when i drag the window

I have tried debugging but am not able to figure these issues out.

Comment: Are you sure your shaders are compiling. Neither of them do for me.

Comment: Change `if (result != GL_FALSE)` to `if (result == GL_FALSE)` in your CompileShader function.

Comment: still having the same issue

Comment: @Iza The program works fine for me, when you change to `if (result == GL_FALSE)`. Did you try  `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;` right before `if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to go whole-hog on Core contexts on macOS if you want anything past GL 2.1:

- Request a versioned Core context via `GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE`, `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR`, and `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR`; it should meet or exceed the `#version` you're specifying in your shaders
- For macOS in particular you [need a forward-compatbile context](https://www.glfw.org/faq.html#41---how-do-i-create-an-opengl-30-context); set `GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT` to `GL_TRUE`
- Core contexts require a [vertex array object (VAO)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) to draw *anything*; for simple stuff you can get away with creating a single one and leaving it bound

All together:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

struct Program
{
    static GLuint Load( const char* shader, ... )
    {
        GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
        va_list args;
        va_start( args, shader );
        while( shader )
        {
            const GLenum type = va_arg( args, GLenum );
            AttachShader( prog, type, shader );
            shader = va_arg( args, const char* );
        }
        va_end( args );
        glLinkProgram( prog );
        CheckStatus( prog );
        return prog;
    }

private:
    static void CheckStatus( GLuint obj )
    {
        GLint status = GL_FALSE;
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderiv( obj, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramiv( obj, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status );
        if( status == GL_TRUE ) return;
        GLchar log[ 1 << 15 ] = { 0 };
        if( glIsShader(obj) ) glGetShaderInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        if( glIsProgram(obj) ) glGetProgramInfoLog( obj, sizeof(log), NULL, log );
        std::cerr << log << std::endl;
        std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    static void AttachShader( GLuint program, GLenum type, const char* src )
    {
        GLuint shader = glCreateShader( type );
        glShaderSource( shader, 1, &src, NULL );
        glCompileShader( shader );
        CheckStatus( shader );
        glAttachShader( program, shader );
        glDeleteShader( shader );
    }
};

const char* vert = 1 + R"GLSL(
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
};
)GLSL";

const char* frag = 1 + R"GLSL(
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;
void main()
{
    color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
)GLSL";

int main(void)
{
    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE );
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;

    GLuint vao = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );

    float positions[6] =
    {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
         0.0f,  0.5f,
         0.5f, -0.5f
    };

    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), 0);

    GLuint shader = Program::Load( vert, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, frag, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, NULL );
    glUseProgram(shader);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteProgram(shader);

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be in vertex shader because in vertex shader "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
here you define vec4 but in you are sending vec2 from glVertexAttribPointer() function.
Try to send vec4 or try this in vertex shader

```
std::string vertexShader =
"#version 330 core\n"
"\n"
"layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;\n"
"\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);\n"
"}\n";
```

Comment: OpenGL will automatically fill unspecified vector components with y = 0, z = 0, w = 1, see 10.3.5 "Transferring Array Elements" in [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf).